# Intellij IDEA Darcula - how to make it print friendly?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I've always been a big fan of the Darcula theme for Intellij IDEA.

The problem is though that if you use it, IDEA will also print everything (code, diagrams, docs etc.) according to Darcula colours - and that's not very printer/paper+ink friendly.

Is there a way around that problem?

EDIT: sadly, I found this issue reported against PyCharm (using the same backend as IDEA AFAIK):

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115890

Comment: Don't print code in the first place! ;-) 

Okay, if you really want to, I guess your best bet is to file a bug against IDEA. Link it to the PyCharm issue, if possible, and have all your colleagues vote for the issue.

Comment: I was trying to print class hierarchy diagrams. Quick switch scheme (Ctrl+backtick, 4) does the thick easy enough so that I will not engage the collagues (at least not this time :))).